# Starting an aniamtion over again with diffrent image

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I am trying to set an image in a imageview run an animation in sequence. Whenever I try and reset the image to start the animation over again it is delayed a little and the animation sequence is ruined any way to solve this?

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();



    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapCompressor.getInstance().compressBitmap(
            photoPaths.remove(0), 250);
    apa1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

    apa1.startAnimation(view_1_anim_a);

    Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapCompressor.getInstance().compressBitmap(
            photoPaths.remove(0), 250);
    apa2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);

    apa2.startAnimation(view_2_anim_a);

    Bitmap bitmap3 = BitmapCompressor.getInstance().compressBitmap(
            photoPaths.remove(0), 250);
    apa3.setImageBitmap(bitmap3);

    apa3.startAnimation(view_3_anim_a);




    view_1_anim_a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            apa1.startAnimation(view_1_anim_b);

        }
    });

    view_1_anim_b.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            apa1.startAnimation(view_1_anim_c);

        }
    });

    view_1_anim_c.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            apa1.startAnimation(view_1_anim_d);


        }
    });

    view_1_anim_d.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {


        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapCompressor.getInstance().compressBitmap(
                    photoPaths.remove(0), 250);
            apa4.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

            apa4.startAnimation(view_1_anim_a)://HERE IT IS DELAYED A BIT AND THE SEQUENCE IS RUINED
        }
    });
```